# How to load jquery in my gsp using layout

Tags: grails

It's really confusing for me to understand the layouts and the page for loading `.js`. Sometimes it get me to madness. In my `layout/smart.gsp` I have this before `</body>`:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

When I use this on:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert('test')
}
```

But in my index.gsp is giving this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. I have to add the `<r:layoutResources/>`at the layout in `</head>` and `</body>` before? Or it's just for the `ApplicationResources.groovy` that and uses `<r:require>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you've put the script tag that loads jQuery at the end of the body, but remember that you need to load jQuery *before* you can use `$()`.  So you need to re-arrange things to put the script tag for jQuery somewhere above the script that's doing `$(document).ready`.

Or use the resources mechanism properly, with the jquery Grails plugin, `require` the jquery module and put your script fragments into `<r:script>`, and Grails should take care of the ordering for you (the Grails plugin loads jQuery in the head rather than at the end of the body).